# Access comparing floating-point numbers "incorrectly"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using MSAccess 2010 on Windows 7 64.

I am comparing two tables in a query. I am joining on a composite PK and selecting rows where table A column A <> table B column A where column A for both tables is a double.

For 120 rows it works. For 28 rows a value of 0.088 in table A column A <> 0.088 in table B column A.

There are no text functions used ANYWHERE.

When I add a column to the query a:[TableA]![ColumnA] - [TableB]![ColumnA] I return values like -1.38777878078145E-17.

When I export the query to Excel and do the math the result = 0.

How is it possible that 0.088 - 0.088 <> 0?
How is it possible that 0.088 double <> 0.088 double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem related to the nature of floating-point numbers in any computing context (not just Access). It seems like a paradox, but the fact is that a `Double` value can *approximately* represent a huge range of numbers very precisely (up to 15 significant digits, ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-HA010233292.aspx#BM2g)), but that representation is almost never *exact*. That's why:

- exact comparisons of floating numbers (e.g. `x=y`) can sometimes fail, and therefore
- you should never rely on a `JOIN` between two `Double` fields.

More information on floating-point numbers is available [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/). Wikipedia also addresses the issue [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

If you have fields with decimal places that require *exact* comparisons then you may want to consider changing them to `Currency` or `Decimal`.

Comment: This is correct. I changed the table structure to a decimal 7, 7 and that showed the values that Access was keeping hidden in the background. 0.088 was being displayed but the actual number was 0.0879999.