# roundings with Access

Tags: ms-access, rounding

With Microsoft Access 2010, I have two Single fields:

A = 1.1
B = 2.1

I create a query where I have defined C=A*B

Microsoft Access says that C = 2.30999994277954
but, in reality, C =2.31

How can I get the right result (2.31)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly off results from operations performed on decimal values can happen if your numeric field size is single or double rather than decimal. Single and double (or floating point) numbers are very close approximations of the "true" numbers, but should not be relied upon if accuracy in operations is required. A related stackoverflow question has more information about this issue: [Access comparing floating-point numbers "incorrectly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845814/access-comparing-floating-point-numbers-incorrectly)

If it's possible to modify the underlying table's design, you should change the field size property for the "A" and "B" fields from single to decimal. After changing the field size BUT BEFORE saving the table, you will also need to adjust the Scale property for "A" and "B" from 0 to whatever number of places to the right of the decimal point you might require. You will likely still have a notice about losing data, but if you adjust the field properties correctly before saving the table, this shouldn't be a problem. You should probably make a copy of the table before doing this so that you can verify that there was no data loss. After saving your table and verifying the changes did not result in data loss, your query should represent A * B accurately.